# Search and Display result with database

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL Database with tablename 'user' . I want to search data on the basis of "ID"number. For example: If I want to search an ID say 14, it should display all the record(firstname, lastname, gender, country,email etc.)for ID=14 .

Here is my code:

data.php

```
<?php
require_once ('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['done']))
{
    $FirstName = $_POST['firstname'];
    $LastName = $_POST['lastname'];
    $DateofBirth =$_POST['dateofbirth'];
    $Email = $_POST['email'];
    $Gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $Country = $_POST['country'];
    $Website = $_POST['website'];
    $Bio = $_POST['bio'];

$CreateSql="INSERT INTO `user` (`First Name`, `Last Name`, `Gender`,`Date of Birth`, `Country`, `Email`, `Website`, `Bio`,`Created Date`)
        VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Gender','$DateofBirth', '$Country', '$Email', '$Website', '$Bio',NOW())";
$insert = mysqli_query($connection,$CreateSql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
if($insert)
    {
        echo  'Data Inserted';
    }else
    {
        echo  'mysqli_error()';
    }
}

//header ("refresh:2; url=index.php");

?>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>View Data</title>
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
    <body>
      <table width="1200" class="table-bordered" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
          <th><center>ID</center></th>
          <th><center>First Name</center></th>
          <th><center>Last Name</center></th>
          <th><center>Gender</center></th>
          <th><center>Date of Birth</center></th>
          <th><center>Registration Date</center></th>
          <th><center>Action</center></th>
        </tr>

<?php
$select = "SELECT * FROM `user` ";
$record = mysqli_query($connection,$select);
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($record))
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['ID']; ?></center></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['First Name']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['Last Name']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['Gender']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['Date of Birth']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['Created Date']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><a href="view.php?ID=<?php echo $data['ID']; ?>">View</a>
            <a href="search.php?ID=<?php echo $data['ID']; ?>">Search</a>
        <a href="edit.php?ID=<?php echo $data['ID']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true">Edit</span></a>
        <a href="delete.php?ID=<?php echo $data['ID']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true">Delete</span></a></center></td>
  <tr>
<?php
}
?>
  </table>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <center><a href="index.php"><input type="submit" name="done" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Add User"></a></center>

            <a href="search.php?ID=<?php echo $data['ID']; ?>"><input type="submit" name="search" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Search ID"></a>
            <input type="text" name="search" value="<?php echo $data['ID']; ?>"
```

search.php

```
<?php
require_once ('connect.php');
 $ID = $_GET['ID'];
?>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>View Data</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
      <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </head>
      <body>
        <table width="1200" border="2" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
          <tr>
            <th><center>ID</center></th>
            <th><center>First Name</center></th>
            <th><center>Last Name</center></th>
            <th><center>Email</center></th>
            <th><center>Gender</center></th>
            <th><center>Date of Birth</center></th>
            <th><center>Country</center></th>
            <th><center>Website</center></th>
            <th><center>Bio </center></th>
            <th><center>Registration Date</center></th>
          </tr>

<?php
$search = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `ID` = '$ID' ");
while($data= mysqli_fetch_array($search))
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['ID']; ?></center></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['First Name']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['Last Name']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['Email']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['Gender']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['Date of Birth']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['Country']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['Website']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['Bio']; ?></center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $data['Created Date']; ?></center></td>
  <tr>
<?php

if($search)
      {
        echo  'Record Found';
      }else
      {
        echo  'mysqli_error()';
      }
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

With the above code I am getting this output:It shows no record for the selected ID.
[image]

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even **[escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)** is not safe!

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. 
It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**.
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. 
You may be asked to amend this code in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

- Debug your code with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. It can help you to
  find the error. Put it on the top of your search.php
- `echo` your SQL statement to check if its valid. You can also copy and run it in phpadmin or whatever you use.

  echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM ...

[PHP error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)